# HTML 5 maze game - What to do after collision detection if the touch event continues?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am working on a maze game using the html5 canvas and javascript (i prefer using the jquery library for coding). - **the game is for mobile devices and I am totaly new with using touch events**

On the canvas, I am adding the maze image - a black and whit gif labyrinth.

I am going to use the trouch in order to navigate through the maze.

Here is what I have done:

1. Add an event listener for the touch:

   window.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
2. Added the function to handle the move:

   function handleMove(e){
       e.preventDefault();

   ```
   // Check the touch position on canvas
   var checkx = event.targetTouches[0].pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
   var checky = event.targetTouches[0].pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

   var collision = checkcollision(checkx,checky);

   if (collision == 0){
       x = checkx;
       y = checky;
       draw(imgWidth,imgHeight,ctx);
   } else {
       // HERE IS THE PROBLEM - WHAT SHOULD I DO? 
       //BECAUSE IF THE TOUCH EVENT CONTINUES, THE COLLISION  
       // FUNCTION WILL HIT THE WHITE COLOR AGAIN 
       //AND THE BALL WHICH I AM NAVIGATING THROUGH THE MAZE WILL 
       // PASS THE BORDER.
   }
   ```

   };
3. Checking for collision - **here is my problem**

What do I do when I hit a black border?

**If the user continues to move and the touch event continues, when he hits white again, the ball which I am navigating through the maze jumps over the black border.**

**So, I could stop the event... any ideas?**

Here is the collision function:

```
function checkcollision(checkx, checky){
        var collision = 0;
        var imgd = ctx.getImageData(checkx, checky, 15, 15);
        pix = imgd.data;
        for (var i = 0; n = pix.length, i < n; i += 4){
            if (pix[i] == 0) {
                collision = 1;
            } else if(pix[i] == 255 && pix[i + 1] == 0){
                winner = "yes";
            }
        }
        //console.log("colision fromn the function: "+collision);
        return collision;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one idea:

I assume that you know the current position of the ball at all times and that the user is constantly touching the screen to move and is not able to just stop touching, move their finger to a new location, and begin touching again to move the ball to that point.

When the `checkcollision` function returns `1`, you know the position of the collision. What you can do is save that position and set a flag that prevents the ball from updating it's position unless the touch event is between the ball and the collision. This would prevent the user from passing through walls no matter the direction of the wall. It would look something like this

```
var updateBall = true;
var collisionPosX, collisionPosY;

function handleMove(e) {
   // do collision check


   if (collision == 0 && updateBall == true) {
     // update ball
   }
   else if (collision == 0 && /* touch is between collisionPos and current ball position */ ){
      updateBall = true;
   }
   else if (updateBall) {
      collisionPosX = checkx;
      collisionPosY = checky;
      updateBall = false;
   }      
}
```

There will be some difficulties in knowing how to write the "is between collisionPos and current ball position" check based on how your game works and what you allow as valid movements (such as riding the wall with the finger and then going into white further down the path, would this teleport the ball to that location because it was valid?). Heck, it could be that doing that kind of check won't work, but hopefully the structure of this design will help you know what kind of check will work.

Again, this is just one idea, so take it for what it's worth.

Comment: It needed some fiddling but your idea rocked! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your other question got removed so i'll answer here:

I guess you are asking to do **chaining of functions or how does that work**.

Take a look:

```
//chaining basics
var obj = {
   a: function(){
        //do something...
        return this;
     },
   b: function() {//do somethingelse 
        return this;
     }
};
```

Then you can call stuff like this...
obj.a().b();

so in your example this what needs to be done:

```
function  makeObj(id){
   var ele = document.getElementById(id);
   this.red= function(){
      ele.style.backgroundColor='red';
        return this;
    };
    this.blue= function(){
      ele.style.backgroundColor='red';
        return this;
    };
  //and so on...
}

var p = new makeObj('paragraph1');
```

or if you wrote makeObj function like this you could all it like this

```
var p = makeObj('paragraph1'); //remember $ is just a character. Which you can use too.

function  makeObj(id){
   var ele = document.getElementById(id);
return {
   red: function(){
      ele.style.backgroundColor='red';
        return this;
    },
   blue: function(){
      ele.style.backgroundColor='blue';
        return this;
    }
  //and so on...
      };
}
```

now you can do this:

```
var p = makeObj('idofelem');
p.red();
p.red().blue();
p.blue():
```